# Is there a way to "listen" for when the user likes, adds, or shares a YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, html, api, youtube-api, listener

I have looked at YouTube's API and could not find a way that could list user's recent activity, so I am wondering if anyone knows if there's a way to have like an Event Listener for when the user interacts with a YouTube video. Any help or clues would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the values change every few seconds and if it does, you can call a function that does what you want if the user interacts with the video.

Comment: Where would I get these "values" you're talking about? Thanks